# How to create new User with an Organization association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

In my webapp my User Signup page has an Organization Name field.  I have an Organization model that `has_many :users`, and my User model `belongs_to :organization`.  When a new user is created, I'd like for the Organization Name value to be used to create a new organization record, and associate it with the user, such that user.organization_id = the new organization id.

This is my users_controller.rb code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @organization = Organization.find(@user.organization_id)
  end

  def create
    @organization = Organization.new(organization_params)
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save && @organization.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the App!"
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Uh oh, there's been an error"
      render 'new'
    end
  end



  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    def organization_params
      params.require(:organization).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Right now both the user record and organization record are being created when a user submits the signup form, but the association is not saved.  The user.organization_id value is nil.

Can you comment on what's wrong, and if there's a good way to do what I'm going for -- maybe with .build?

Thanks!
Brennan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! .build will work, but because its a single association back, you will be using the association name in your build command, ie `build_organization`

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @user.build_organization(organization_params)
  if @user.save
    blah blah blah
```

You only need to save the user (not @organization) if done this way because the association is taken care of.

Comment: Thanks JTG!  I'll try that now.

Comment: This worked like a charm, JTG - thanks so much!  I've been struggling with it for days ;-)

Comment: Is there a good way to validate for the presence of an organization association with this method?  Right now you can create a user without an organization and it still goes through.

Comment: @bnzelener Put `validates :organization, presence: true` in your `app/models/user.rb`.  If you have any more questions, feel free to ask a new SO question (after researching and if you're still stuck, of course ;)  ).  And feel free to accept this as the answer to help others who may have the same question later.

Answer (score 0):

At user_params permit :organization_id ;)

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :organization_id)
end
```

EDIT: You also need to set organization_id somewhere for user - if you're not doing it in form (like with select or some else field) you can use .build method.